# How to verify if string represents a hex number in go

Tags: go

This mostly works:

```
import "encoding/hex"

func isHexString(s string) bool {
    _, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
    return err == nil
}
```

However, we also may want to support odd length hex strings. Checking against hex.ErrLength doesn't work because this error precedes whether the string contains hex characters. I guess could manipulate string to contain the appropriate number of characters and apply both checks but it seems like there should be better way.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#DecodeString

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your goal is to parse the hex digits as a integer or unsigned integer, then call [strconv.ParseInt](https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseInt) or [strconv.ParseUint](https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseUnt):

```
n, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 16, 64)
if err != nil {
    // s is not a valid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

F.Y.I.

Eventhough `strconv.ParseUint()` works fine in most cases, **if you get "value out of range" error** with `strconv.ParseUint()` and hash-kind-values, consider using `hex.Decode()` as below.

```golang
dst := make([]byte, hex.DecodedLen(len(s)))

if _, err := hex.Decode(dst, []byte(strOut)); err != nil {
    // s is not a valid
}
```

It will detect if the input is odd length with `odd length hex string` error as well.

- [View it online](https://go.dev/play/p/Emt7WyUopwd) @ Go Playground